# Can't seem to find the issue with the requestID parameter for the request header

Tags: python-3.x, rest, python-requests, json-rpc

I am trying to pull data from a REST API that uses a *"similar standard to JSON RPC"*. The params I am passing look right according to the documentation [here](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) and [here](https://pypi.org/project/jsonrpc2/#json-rpc2-example).
The error I am receiving is `...message:"Header missing request ID"...`. I am unsure what I am missing that would properly declare the requestID.

I have looked at the documentation provided via the API I am trying to pull data from but it's not very helpful considering it's all in PHP and cURL. I am trying to complete this task using python-requests.

```
getParams = {'method': 'getCustomers', 'params':{'where':'', 'limit': 2}, 'id': 'getCustomers'}
```

Result:

```
{"result":null,"error":{"code":102,"message":"Header missing request ID","data":[]},"id":null}
```

The return result should contain a list of All Customers and their attributes in JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is nothing wrong with the code I am using. There is an issue with the API I am attempting to call.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I was getting the same error back and was required to send a X-Request-ID header. I fixed it by adding the following to my headers:

```
headers = {
    'X-Request-ID': str(uuid.uuid1()) # generate GUID based on host & time
    ...
```

Note that (for me) the GUID needed to be of a specific format (e.g. matching the Regex `^[{]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[}]?$`
taken from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-validate-guid-globally-unique-identifier-using-regular-expression/). For example, it still gave the same error if I just sent "test".